# Camera view finder comes up black on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone app that presents a UIImagePickerController for users to take a photo. It works fine on iPhone, iPod and an iPad mini, but on one iPad 3 it comes up like this.

[image: black viewfinder]

Can anyone think of a reason this would happen? There's nothing blocking the lens, and all other camera apps work fine on the device.

I'm presenting the controller like this:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    self.picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;

    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.picker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
    {
        self.picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
    }

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I would really appreciate any help

Thanks